# URL rewrite - one more rule

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am working on the URL-rewrite of my site. So far, it works great. I got the following code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /calendster/

RewriteRule ^admin2($|/) - [L]
RewriteRule ^test.php($|/) - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([a-z]+)/(\d+)/?$ index.php?site=$1&cmd=$2&id=$3 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([a-z]+)/?$ index.php?site=$1&cmd=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(\d+)/?$ index.php?site=$1&id=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?site=$1 [L,QSA]
```

With the code showed above, I have these URL-re

```
test.php?site=hi  --> www.domain.com/hi
test.php?site=hi&id=1  --> www.domain.com/hi/1
test.php?site=hi&cmd=test  --> www.domain.com/hi/test
test.php?site=hi&cmd=test&id=1  --> www.domain.com/hi/test/1
```

I would like one more rule. I would like to

```
test.php?site=users&ustr=haris-skrijelj  --> www.domain.com/users/haris-skrijelj
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: [Please read this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16389034/1729885).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this would work:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([a-z-]+)/?$ index.php?site=$1&ustr=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
```

However if on users it's also possible to have users without a dash then you would have to make it more specific with:

```
RewriteRule ^(users)/([a-z-]+)/?$ index.php?site=$1&ustr=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Or it will conflict with your other rule.

And the complete rule:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /calendster/

RewriteRule ^admin2($|/) - [L]
RewriteRule ^test.php($|/) - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([a-z]+)/(\d+)/?$ index.php?site=$1&cmd=$2&id=$3 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([a-z-]+)/?$ index.php?site=$1&ustr=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([a-z]+)/?$ index.php?site=$1&cmd=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(\d+)/?$ index.php?site=$1&id=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?site=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I used your example, but it is conflicting with the other rules.

Comment: @hskrijelj which one? the one at the bottom? if so use the 2nd rule which is a more exact rule to avoid conflict.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/users/(\w+)$ test.php?site=users&ustr=$1
```